# Nginx unable to server static and media images

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have a django app on DigitalOcean droplet running using gunicorn and nginx. The site is working but the static files are giveing 404. Below is my '/etc/nginx/sites-available/django-project' file:

```
server {

        #listen 80 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name aakar.in;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        #access_log off;

        client_max_body_size 4G;
        #server_name _;

        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location /media  {
           alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
        }

        location / {

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM N$
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction made:

```
location /static/ {
            alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static/;
        }
```

Working now.